# order from recent date DataTables dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I made a table using DataTables plugin.
I created a column called "Date" wich contains some dates. With the button near "Date" I can order records but I have to use this format for the dates dd/mm/yyyy so the order is wrong.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped" id="mydata">
  <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Schedina</th>
   <th>Quota</th>
   <th>Stake</th>   
   <th>Data</th>
   <th>Risultato</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td value="2020-11-15">15/11/2020</td>
    <td>In corso</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>4.52</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td value="2017-04-07">07/04/2017</td>
    <td>Vinto</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>prova 123<br> prova</td>
    <td>2.01</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td value="2017-01-15">15/01/2017</td>
    <td>In corso</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>oggi</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td value="2017-01-15">15/01/2017</td>
    <td>Vinto</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>1212dwed</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td value="2017-01-15">15/01/2017</td>
    <td>Perso</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td value="2017-01-14">14/01/2017</td>
    <td>Vinto</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td value="2017-01-13">13/01/2017</td>
    <td>Perso</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>1.94</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td value="2017-01-12">12/01/2017</td>
    <td>Vinto</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>1.95</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td value="2017-01-12">12/01/2017</td>
    <td>Perso</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>1.93</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td value="2017-01-12">12/01/2017</td>
    <td>Vinto</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>Nad</td>
    <td>1.82</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>12/01/2017</td>
    <td>Vinto</td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <script>
  $('#mydata').DataTable( {
   responsive: true
  } );
  </script>
```

This is why I didn't post it. There is an error in lineno 0 . But in my file i don't have any error

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing dates as strings, but the strings contain the day at start. Let's implement a helper `function`:

```
function helper(input) {
   var dateElements = input.split("/");
   return dateElements[2] + dateElements[1] + dateElements[0];
}
```

and use this to convert your elements to their desired format. Then you will be able to compare them, as year will be at the start, month will follow and day will be at the end.

Comment: how can i call this function in <td> tag?

Comment: @Riccardo what should trigger the execution of the function?

Comment: In input i have to send 16/01/2017 or 2017-01-16?

Comment: @Riccardo you need to send the former, since the purpose of this function is to convert that to a date string, so the input of 16/01/2017 should be converted to 20170116

Comment: if i write it in console it returns /61

Comment: @Riccardo you are right, that was a typo from my part, I did not hit the / button with enough force and did not see I ended up with an empty string. Please check out my edited post and sorry for the inconvenience.